# Creating jQuery helper plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I write a jQuery helper plug-in so that I can invoke it with `$.myPlugin()`, as opposed to `$.fn.myPlugin()`?

With a plug-in created in the following way, you can only call it by `$("selector").myPlugin()` or `$.fn.myPlugin()`.

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
  };
})( jQuery );
```

, where `myPlugin()` is a helper function that doesn't need the `this` reference. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@andres has provided one of the possibilities of defining a jQuery plugin, though it's more usual that you define a plugin by using `$.extend` functionality.

```
(function($) { // plugin closure

    var defaults = { ... };

    $.extend({
        myPlugin: function(options) { // when options are needed
            options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            // functionality afterwards
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(function( $ ){

  $.myPlugin = function() {

      var HelperDate1 = function() { ... };
      var HelperDate2 = function() { ... };
      var HelperMath1 = function() { ... };


      return {
             method1: HelperDate1,
             method2: HelperDate2,
             method2: HelperMath1

         };

  }();

})(jQuery);
```

Use:

```
$.myPlugin.method1();
$.myPlugin.method2();
```

But you do not need jQuery for this.

**EDIT:**

```
var myHelper = (function($){

  var 
    pub = this,   //public
    pri = {};     //private


  // public method
  pub.HelperDate1 = function() {
        //...
  };

  pub.HelperDate2 = function() {
        //...
        pri._xFunctionPrivate2(); // can call private methods
  };

  pub.HelperMath1 = function() { 
        //... 
  };

  // public event method
  pub.InputEventClick = function(event) {
        //...
        // this is the element input, not the environment of the helper
        $(this).val("new value"); // example

  };

  // private method
  pri._xFunctionPrivate1 = function() { 
        //... 
  };

  pri._xFunctionPrivate2 = function() { 
        //... 
  };


  return public;

}).call({}, jQuery); //The first parameter is in context (this)
```

Use:

```
myHelper.HelperDate1();
myHelper.HelperDate2();
$("input").bind("click", myHelper.InputEventClick);
myHelper._xFunctionPrivate1() // ERROR _xFunctionPrivate1 is private
```

Comment: What do you mean *he does not need jQuery for this*?

Comment: If you just want to make a helper without this, you can do so without jQuery